# Add-NetNatStaticMapping not working with Hyper-V Windows 8 VM

Tags: hyper-v, nat

I used this to set up port forwarding into my Windows-VM from my host:

Add-NetNatStaticMapping -NatName "MyNat" -Protocol TCP -ExternalIPAddress 0.0.0.0 -InternalIPAddress 192.168.100.11 -InternalPort 22 -ExternalPort
 2222

I can connect to port 22 on the machine, but I cannot connect to 2222, using

ssh -p 2222 IEUser@192.168.200.20

Why does this not work?

I thought you needed to set up a VMSwitch, assign it an IP-address, set up the nat network and then add the nat rules.

Comment: have you figured it out?

Comment: Not really.. I guess it has something to do with some of our group policies. In the end, I changed my setup and logged into the VM directly. I didn't need the port forwarding anymore.